# How to find documents in mongoose by populate field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with mongoose. When I make some field referenced to other collection, I lose ability to search by this field. I don't know how to describe my problem correctly, so look at the examples please.

Schema:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
content: String,
url: String,
author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
mainImage: String,
type: String
});
```

Query:

```
Post.find({author: user._id})
    .then(posts => res.send(posts))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
```

Returns nothing. But if I change "author" field to String, it will works, but without populate. :(

Upd:
I can't believe. I made this:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
content: String,
url: String,
author: {type: String, ref: 'User'},
mainImage: String,
type: String
});
```

Just change type to string. Omg I can't figure out how it working. How mongoose knows which field I need to compare in ref collection? I mean there is no direct link to "_id" field (see query). Can someone explain?

Upd2:

Auhtor schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
id: String,
about: String,
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
email: String,
avatar: String,
city: String,
country: String,
dateOfBirth: String,
password: String,
},
{
  timestamps: true
})
```

As you can see, I using additional "id" field just in purpose to give users simple numeric id for url (/id1 etc). But I am sure this isn't the source of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change the `type: Schema.ObjectId` to `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: Do me a favor. Change your find request to finding all posts, so `Post.find({})`, then populate the author field, so add to the end of that `.populate('author')` (this is between the find() and the .then()). What does this give you?

Comment: It gives me all posts with authors, as expected. But see update, I found working solution, but I can't understand how it works

Comment: Can you add your author schema to the question please?

Comment: So one thing you could do is get rid of your id field, and replace it with the _id. You can define the _id field in your author schema, like this: `_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }`. Now in your database, instead of each author being referenced by an _id of type ObjectId, it will be a string.